# How can i make use of makefile exported values while running script file

Tags: make

How can i make use of makefile exported values while running script file. 
I have makefile with some exported values. I am running one script file. i need to make use of variables exported in makefile when i run script file.

Used include in script file , but the command is not supported in script file. what is the solution to handle this problem?

Comment: Hi! Can you show relevant excerpts of what you tried, and a specific example of what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include in your script line like:

```
. /path/to/makefile
```

this will exec the file (makefile, make it executable) in the shell instance of your script
Also you can use

```
source /path/to/makefile
```

Comment: But facing compilation problem of executing makefile in the shell instance where the command ifeq is used in makefile

Comment: So set them explicitly in shell: . /path/to/file